# Using auto with initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

I have question regarding interaction between auto and initializer list. Example code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
auto a{ 1 };
auto b = { 1 };
auto c = 1;

std::cout << typeid(a).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << typeid(b).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << typeid(c).name() << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

Gives output:

```
int
class std::initializer_list<int>
int
```

Which is kind of confusing. I'm posting this question as a [followup to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38099768/comparison-of-two-auto-variables/38100522?noredirect=1#comment63641762_38100522). What should happen? I've did some research and it seems that `auto c = 1;` is [illegal now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406212/why-does-auto-a-1-compile-in-c), and it seems that it works because compilers allow this as a backwards compatibility patch. Does this apply also to `auto a{1}`?

Comment: `auto c = 1;` is not illegal.  `1` has a type the compiler can deduce.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612262/why-does-auto-x3-deduce-an-initializer-list

Comment: `auto c = 1` is valid c++. The question you linked deals with c, which is very much a different language.

Comment: So you're aware, C++11 requires that `a` is an initializer list. C++17 changes that to `int`, but GCC does that in C++11 regardless.

Comment: @chris thanks! Can you provide some documentation for change between C++11 and C++17?

Comment: @MaciekGrynda, There's a bunch in Nathan's link.

Comment: @MaciekGrynda - Or try this question from yesterday: [What are the new features in C++17?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060436/what-are-the-new-features-in-c17)